# what is {% trans "This is the title." %} used for,i can't understand the api

Tags: python, django

i know the {% trans  %}  is for translation,

and how can i translate {% trans "This is the title." %}  to chinese.

thanks

---

```
D:\zjm_code\register2>python D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-adm
in.py compilemessages
processing file django.po in D:\zjm_code\register2\locale\cn\LC_MESSAGES
msgfmt: iconv failure
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't follow the documentation?

3 steps:

1. Add `{% load i18n %}` in the template (as Michał Ludwiński says). Put the `{% trans %}` in your templates, or `_` in python code, etc.
2. Build a translation dictionary:

   - Run `django-admin.py makemessages -l cn` (cn = China language code) in your Django project root.
   - Edit `locale/cn/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`. Just under `msgid "Hello!"` change `msgstr ""` to  to `msgstr "nihao"`. Don't change `msgid`. You can use unicode, but I'd use pinyin until you are sure everything else works.
   - Run `django-admin.py compilemessages`
3. Setup language translation. You might need to enable some middle-ware.

Comment: hi,wisty,i usd your way to do it,
1 and 2 are ok,and 3,i change 'LANGUAGE_CODE' in settings.py from 'en-us'  to 'cn',when i fresh my 127.0.0.1:8000 ,it also be english,

Comment: #: .\views.py:16 .\django_authopenid\views.py:232
msgid "E-mail"
msgstr "邮箱"

Answer (score 3):

before you will try to use {% trans %} blocktag you need to type

```
{% load i18n %}
```

then you can use the tag to type in the text you want to be translated (one thing is important - the text ought to be in main project language which is set in settings)

if you have already some text you want to translate type in your projects main dir:

```
./manage.py makemessages -l pl
```

where "**pl**" can by country code of the language of choice. this command will make django scripts generate a right localization file located in the ./locale/(language-code)/LC_MESSAGES/django.po.

after doing the translation stuff you simply type

```
./manage.py compilemessages
```

and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[I18n in Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#topics-i18n)

Comment: Ask a real question, get a real answer.